# What are some genuine sites for content writing?

Tags: creative-writing, career, freelance

What are some good genuine sites on the web for paid freelance content writing, proof-reading etc.? Even though I do not have any degree in journalism (full-time or part-time), I believe I have a fairly good command over the English language and can use it to my advantage. That being said, what are the chances of a newbie breaking into content writing, especially with a background like mine?

Comment: I've seen this Q before. I think it's a duplicate, maybe at Cyn's link but I thought it was a different one.

Comment: To me it also looks like the other question is asking the same thing and some of the answers, like [this one](https://writing.stackexchange.com/a/35413/23159) seem like they would be very helpful. if your question is different from the other one please [edit] it to show in which ways it's different. Otherwise this could get closed as a duplicate to make it easier for others with a similar question to find those answers in the future. Duplicates mean multiple ways to phrase a problem and a central place to find relevant answers.